Unable to upload a PDF file to Firebase Storage (RNFirebase) using react-native
I need to upload the pdf file to firebase storage. I am able to retrieve the URI of the document using react-native-document-picker. However, I am receiving errors while making a blob or converting the doc file to base64.
// One approach of converting doc file to base 64. It converts it but fails when trying to upload // it to the storage giving "NativeFirebaseError: [storage/unknown]" error.
async handleURIConversionToBase64(uri) {
    return RNFS.readFile(uri, 'base64').then(base64String =>
      base64String


    ).catch(error => {
      console.log('error while RNFS: ', error);
    });
  }

// Another approach of making a blob is giving me "RangeError: Failed to construct 'Response': The status provided (0) is outside the range [200, 599]." error.
  async getBlob(uri) {
    return fetch(uri).then(response => {
      return response.blob().then(blobFile => {
        return blobFile;
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error while blobbing: ', error);
      });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('error while fetching: ', error);
    });
  }

// This is what I have tried so far. I have used stringDecodedURI and stringDecodedURIComponent // interchangeably but of no use. Also, I have used handleURIConversionToBase64 and getBlob but // nothing helped.

const stringDecodedURI = decodeURI(uri);
const stringDecodedURIComponent = decodeURIComponent(uri);
this.getBlob(`${stringDecodedURIComponent}/${fileName}`).then(blob => {
const storageRef = storage.ref(JobAssets.getStorageRefString(orgID, newJobAssetID));
const unsubscribe = storageRef.putFile(blob).on('state_changed',
                snapshot => {
                  const progressNumber = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                  const progress = progressNumber.toString().slice(0, 4);
                  this.setState({ progress });
                },
                err => {
                  console.log('error 1: ', err);
                  reject(err);
                  unsubscribe();
                },
                () => {
                  const url = storageRef.getDownloadURL();
                  console.log('url');
                  resolve(url);
                  this.setState({ fileUploading: false });
                  unsubscribe();
                }
              );
            });

Any help would be appreciated. TIA!
